# Why might this code be giving me null?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimage

**Scroll down to EDIT 1. This top bit is irrelevant now.**

This is my code:

```
NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [self.media objectAtIndex:index];
    NSLog(@"dictionary: %@", dictionary);
    NSString *originalImagePath = [dictionary objectForKey:@"OriginalImage"];
    NSLog(@"path: %@", originalImagePath);
    UIImage *originalImage = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:originalImagePath];
    NSLog(@"original image: %@", originalImage);
    return originalImage;
```

And my NSLog:

```
dictionary: {
    IsInPhotoLibrary = 1;
    MediaType = 0;
    OriginalImage = "/var/mobile/Applications/5E25F369-9E05-4345-A0A2-381EDB3321B8/Documents/Images/E9904811-B463-4374-BD95-4AD472DC71A6.jpg";
}
path: /var/mobile/Applications/5E25F369-9E05-4345-A0A2-381EDB3321B8/Documents/Images/E9904811-B463-4374-BD95-4AD472DC71A6.jpg
original image: (null)
```

Any ideas why this might be coming out as null, despite everything appearing to be in place?

EDIT:

This is the code to write the image to file:

```
+(NSString *)writeImageToFile:(UIImage *)image {
    NSData *fullImageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0f);

NSString *path = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents/Images/"];
NSString *name = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.jpg", [JEntry generateUuidString]];
NSString *filePath = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:name];
[fullImageData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
NSLog(@"original image 2: %@", [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:filePath]);
}
```

This NSLog also comes out as null. So the problem lies here, most likely. Any ideas?

EDIT 2:

So, back-tracing even more now, and I've realised that it's because this fails:

```
[fullImageData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
```

You can return a bool on that line, telling if it was successful or not, and it's returning NO for me. Any ideas why this might be?

EDIT 3:

The image that gets passed in is NULL. Trying to figure out where that's gone wrong now.

Comment: I don't think that path for the image is correct, probably yoy are not getting it properly

Comment: You mean it might be pointing to a location without an image, or the file string doesn't look right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Almost certainly your file does not exist. Modify your code as follows to log if a file exists or not:

```
NSString *originalImagePath = [dictionary objectForKey:@"OriginalImage"];
NSLog(@"path: %@", originalImagePath);
BOOL fileExists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:originalImagePath];
NSLog(@"file exists: %d", fileExists);
```

Answer (score 2):

Possible Reasons:

- The file at originalImagePath does not exist.
- UIImage can not initialize an image from the specified file, because the data is corrupted (maybe the data is empty or incomplete)
- the file can not be accessed because of iOS file permissions (i.e. when accessing files beyond the app sandbox)

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked that the image file is really placed on path in dictionary? You may use the [iExplorer](http://www.macroplant.com/iexplorer/) utility for that.

Also pay attention to the file name case, so it's extension is 'jpg' not 'JPG'.

Finally you should check, whether it's a valid image file, by opening it with some image viewer.

Answer (score 1):

are you sure that the jpg file "E9904811-B463-4374-BD95-4AD472DC71A6.jpg" is there in that folder?
try to open the app file installed in the iPhone/ipad simulator clicking on yourFile.app
with ctrl key and choose to open package contents the open your folder images...

to get a fast link to your documents folder:

```
NSArray *dirPaths;
NSString *docsDir;
dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, 
                                               NSUserDomainMask, YES);
docsDir = [dirPaths objectAtIndex:0];
NSLog(@"doc:%@",docsDir);
```

your app should be in its parent folder